# Normal time for compiling scss with yeoman server?

Tags: performance, development-environment, sass, yeoman

When running `yeoman server` and updating even the simplest SCSS file I have to wait around 5 seconds for the browser to update. I'm on a MacBook Air.

Is this the standard? It is sort of curbing my coding speed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, this is a bug and it should be fixed in version 1.0.

Source: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/820#issuecomment-12912452

I have found that you can disable the `force: true` in Gruntfile.js, this will help with Compass/SCSS speed. Also if you are including a lot of image assets, right now it will be very slow, try limiting this.